# Why is the difference between the code generated in postman and by httpsnippet?

Tags: postman, code-generation

I was trying to use httpSnippet to generate client-code in C# and I got

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.apyhub.com/extract/text/word-file");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("apy-token", "APY0kllzrWDJ1AXxg3cfjxwfAhrXaSuarykmVh2gqleNPi0LujGn4vflrsu1MC58");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001", "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n@\"test.docx\"\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--\r\n", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

which is differed from I got in Postman

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://api.apyhub.com")
{
  MaxTimeout = -1,
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
var request = new RestRequest("/extract/text/word-file", Method.Post);
request.AddHeader("apy-token", "APY0kllzrWDJ1AXxg3cfjxwfAhrXaSuarykmVh2gqleNPi0LujGn4vflrsu1MC58");
request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
request.AddFile("file", "/path/to/file");
RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

mainly `request.AddParameter` in my code when used kong/HTTPsnippet and `request.AddFile` in Postman.

I want to achieve similar to Postman, Can any one help please?